# Inserting an entry into MySQL using Squeryl in Play! framework 2.0

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.0, squeryl

So I'm new to the Play! Framework, and even newer to Scala and Squeryl, but I'm trying to do a simple REST application. Right now I'm testing and trying to get setup with Squeryl. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.artima.com/articles/play2_scala_squeryl.html) for getting setup with Squeryl and evolutions to SQL.

Now that the schema evolutions work, and the database is set I created the squeryl model like this:

```
case class App(
  name: String, 
  description: String, 
  website: String = "", 
  callback_url: String = "", 
  access_level: String = "", 
  consumer_key: String = "", 
  access_token: String = "",
  application_icon: String = "",
  organization_name: String = "",
  organization_website: String = "",
  created_on: Integer = 0,
  updated_on: Integer = 0) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {
  val id: Long = 0
}

case class Access_Token(
  token : String,
  token_secret : String,
  access_level : Integer) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {
  val id: Long = 0
}

object AppDB extends Schema {
  val applications = table[App]("applications")
  val access_tokens = table[Access_Token]
}
```

So in my controller I had this line of code that I thought would insert a new entry:

```
def create = Action { implicit request =>
        val entry = AppDB.applications.insert(new App("hello world", "just a test app", "http://www.com/"))
        Ok("New application entry made: " + entry.name)
    }
```

But I only get an error: [ExceptionInInitializerError: null]

What am i doing wrong? I wrote that based off of [this in the squeryl docs](http://squeryl.org/inserts-updates-delete.html)

I've been struggling with this, every example I have found only show how to do things with data via a form or some form helper they have, but what about POST, PUT, GET, DELETE requests in Play! framework? I haven't seen anything relating to REST yet.

Comment: Just about given up, working with anorm currently

Comment: Seems like some stuff in playframework to me. (Not squeryl.)
BTW, I'm using liftweb (for a year already) and I'm happy with it.

Comment: Can you post a bit of the stack trace?  I'd like to see if it's originating from a Squeryl related package, or from Play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just using anorm now, It's not squeryl but the Play! framework that's making the integration tough for me.